# validateEagerly() method in Retrofit 2.0 (beta 2)

Tags: android, retrofit

What exactly does `validateEagerly()` (Retrofit 2.0 beta 2) method do? 
Where can I apply this method?

JavaDoc says that `When calling create on the resulting Retrofit instance, eagerly validate the configuration of all methods in the supplied interface.` but this description is not so clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`validateEagerly()` validates the configuration you have provided when building your `Retrofit` instance. This will inspect your interface annotations for valid Retrofit annotations, inspection of arguments and method arguments, if they are consistent with the annotations set, also this checks for possible incorrect method return types (different than `Call<T>`).

The inspection is usually called before you build your `Retrofit` instance.

```
private Retrofit getRetrofit() {
        OkHttpClient okClient = getOkHttpClient();
        GsonBuilder builder = getGsonBuilder();
        Retrofit.Builder retrofitBuilder = new Retrofit.Builder();
        retrofitBuilder.client(okClient);
        retrofitBuilder.baseUrl(API_ENDPOINT);
        retrofitBuilder.addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(builder.create()));
        retrofitBuilder.validateEagerly();
        return retrofitBuilder.build();
    }
```

It can throw `IllegalArgumentException` with different message and cause, if something is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to validate your all methods in the Interface as soon as possible , you would like to `validateEagerly(true)`

```
  public <T> T create(final Class<T> service) {
Utils.validateServiceInterface(service);
if (validateEagerly) {//here 
  eagerlyValidateMethods(service);
}
return (T) Proxy.newProxyInstance(service.getClassLoader(), new Class<?>[] { service },
    new InvocationHandler() {
      private final Platform platform = Platform.get();

      @Override public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object... args)
          throws Throwable {
        // If the method is a method from Object then defer to normal invocation.
        if (method.getDeclaringClass() == Object.class) {
          return method.invoke(this, args);
        }
        if (platform.isDefaultMethod(method)) {
          return platform.invokeDefaultMethod(method, service, proxy, args);
        }
        ServiceMethod serviceMethod = loadServiceMethod(method);
        OkHttpCall okHttpCall = new OkHttpCall<>(serviceMethod, args);
        return serviceMethod.callAdapter.adapt(okHttpCall);
      }
    });
  }

      // validate your all methods
  private void eagerlyValidateMethods(Class<?> service) {
    Platform platform = Platform.get();
    for (Method method : service.getDeclaredMethods()) {
      if (!platform.isDefaultMethod(method)) {
        loadServiceMethod(method);
       }
    }
   }

  //thie method will cash method in LinkedHashMap
  ServiceMethod loadServiceMethod(Method method) {
    ServiceMethod result;
    synchronized (serviceMethodCache) {
      result = serviceMethodCache.get(method);
      if (result == null) {
        result = new ServiceMethod.Builder(this, method).build();
        serviceMethodCache.put(method, result);
      }
    }
    return result;
  }
```